# How to get all contact number associated with that contact name android

Tags: android, android-contentprovider, android-contacts

I've been trying to make multi contact picker list with checkbox. I already created Multi Contact Picker with contact having atleast one phone number in its contact.

#### Que

Now I've added contact with in `ListView`. But contact appear with single contact number in it, it's taking first phone number which is saved in `Contact` Application. I've added `LinkedHashMap` & `Set` to add `indexer` on the Contact List.

Did `LinkedHashMap` or `Set` is removing duplicate values from Collections?

*How can i fetch all the phone number associated with that contact name?*

Code Snippet:-

```
ContentResolver cr = getContentResolver();
    String selection = Data.HAS_PHONE_NUMBER + " > '" + ("0") + "'";
    
    Cursor cur = cr.query(Data.CONTENT_URI, new String[] { Data.CONTACT_ID, Data.MIMETYPE, Email.ADDRESS,
            Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME, Phone.NUMBER }, selection, null, Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME);

    
     Contact contact;
    if (cur.getCount() > 0) {

        while (cur.moveToNext()) {

            String id = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Data.CONTACT_ID));

            String mimeType = cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Data.MIMETYPE));

            if (allContacts.containsKey(id)) {
                // update contact
                contact = allContacts.get(id);
            } else {
                contact = new Contact();
                allContacts.put(id, contact);
                // set photoUri
                contact.setContactPhotoUri(getContactPhotoUri(Long.parseLong(id)));
            }

            if (mimeType.equals(StructuredName.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                // set name
                contact.setContactName(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Contacts.DISPLAY_NAME)));

            if (mimeType.equals(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE))
                // set phone munber
                contact.setContactNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)));
        }
    }

    cur.close();
    // get contacts from hashmap
    contacts.clear();
    contacts.addAll(allContacts.values());
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These is just a temporary fix as of now, I've been trying to add *all contact number* associated with *same contact person* inside `android.provider.ContactsContract`.

I've added *all contact number* associated with *same contact person* inside beans by appending with `delimiter(",")` which i can fetch back using `Tokenizer`. But no idea to know which kinda contact type it is whether HOME, WORK, OFFICE , it's less important to me as of now.

Fix:

```
if (mimeType.equals(Phone.CONTENT_ITEM_TYPE)){
// set phone number
    if (contact.getContactNumber().toString().length() == 0) {                   
         contact.setContactNumber(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("\\D", ""));
    } else {                      
         contact.setContactNumber(contact.getContactNumber().toString().concat(", ").concat(cur.getString(cur.getColumnIndex(Phone.NUMBER)).replaceAll("\\D", "")));//One can add possible contacts "(-/,"
    }
}
```